# BST node with no children not being deleted

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

My BST is not removing the node without any children after it removes a node with children.

Remove function:

```
private Node remove(Node current, Pair k) throws DictionaryException {
        if (current == null) {
            throw new DictionaryException("Key does not exist");
        }

        if (k.compareTo(current.data.getKey()) < 0) {
            current.left = remove(current.left, k);
        } else if (k.compareTo(current.data.getKey()) > 0) {
            current.right = remove(current.right, k);
        } else {
            if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
                current = null;
            } else if (current.right == null) {
                current = current.left;
            } else if (current.left == null) {
                current = current.right;
            } else {
                Record smallest = smallest(current.right).data;
                current.data = smallest;
                remove(current.right, smallest.getKey());
            }
        }
        return current;
    }
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair key1 = new Pair("homework", "text");
    Record record1 = new Record(key1, "hello world");

    Pair key2 = new Pair("course", "text");
    Record record2 = new Record(key2, "world hello");

    Pair key3 = new Pair("class", "text");
    Record record3 = new Record(key3, "bean man");

    Pair key4 = new Pair("computer", "text");
    Record record4 = new Record(key4, "despacito");

    Pair key5 = new Pair("four", "text");
    Record record5 = new Record(key5, "zebras");

    OrderedDictionary od = new OrderedDictionary();

    try {
        od.put(record1);
        od.put(record2);
        od.put(record3);
        od.put(record4);
        od.put(record5);
    } catch (DictionaryException e) {
        System.out.println("exception in main - put");
    }

    try {
        od.remove(key2);
    } catch (DictionaryException e){
        System.out.println("exception in main - remove");
    }

    od.preOrder();
```

I would expect that `od.preOrder();` would return "homework four class computer". But instead, it returns: "homework four class computer four". For some reason, it's not deleting the "four" that was the right child of "Course" and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Something is tricky when the root element is to be removed. You can do it by setting the `root-right-child` as the `right-child` of the rightmost child of the `root-left-child`, or vice versa, rather than modifying the value of root element and removing the rightmost element of right branch.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... simply change `remove(current.right, smallest.getKey());` to `current.right = remove(current.right, smallest.getKey());` in `remove(Node current, Pair k)` so that it references the correct node